Getting this error in anchor while doing anchor build
error: custom attribute panicked
--> programs/cpi-programs/src/lib.rs:6:1
|
6 | #[program]
| ^^^^^^^^^^
|
= help: message: Safety checks failed: Failed to get program path
error: could not compile cpi-programs (lib test) due to 1 previous error
Error: Building IDL failed

Please add your code
